# Remove Dictionary entries based on specific criteria in a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
List = [ {hostname: server1, username: john}
         {hostname: server2, username: jack}
         {hostname: server2, username: jonny}
         {hostname: server3, username: jules}
         {hostname: server1, username: jonny}
         {hostname: server1, username: jeff} ]
```

So now I want just a dictionary per hostname and if there are several entries per hostname, I want to remove them based on a list of prefered users or so ...
For example if there is server1 with a user john, jonny, jeff then I want to keep the dict with john and remove the others, if there is no john, then keep the one with jonny and so on and if there is no one from my list to prefer then I dont care, just remove others and stay with one. So in the end the above example would look like this

```
List = [ {hostname: server1, username: john}
         {hostname: server2, username: jonny}
         {hostname: server3, username: jules} ]
```

EDIT: As response to the comments:
I have not even an idea how to do that.

1. How can I find double entries in my List per dictionary values?
2. How can I compare them and delete other except one?
3. Should I delete the entry from my list or should I create a new list and only add single entries from my old list?

My test code currently looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 UserPref = ['john', 'jonny', 'jack']
 List = [{'hostname': 'server1', 'username': 'john'},
         {'hostname': 'server2', 'username': 'jack'},
         {'hostname': 'server2', 'username': 'jonny'},
         {'hostname': 'server3', 'username': 'jules'},
         {'hostname': 'server1', 'username': 'jonny'},
         {'hostname': 'server1', 'username': 'jeff'}]

 for item in List:
    if item.get('hostname') in List and item.get('username') not in UserPref:
        del item
 print List
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @vogomatix, the following Python script should do what you need:

```
user_list = [
    {'hostname': 'server1', 'username': 'john'},
    {'hostname': 'server2', 'username': 'jack'},
    {'hostname': 'server2', 'username': 'jonny'},
    {'hostname': 'server3', 'username': 'jules'},
    {'hostname': 'server1', 'username': 'jonny'},
    {'hostname': 'server1', 'username': 'jeff'}]

def sort_by_preferred_users(key):
    preferred_users = ['john', 'jonny', 'jeff'] 
    username = key['username']
    return preferred_users.index(username) if username in preferred_users else len(preferred_users)

user_list.sort(key=sort_by_preferred_users)
new_user_list = []
server_list = []

for d in user_list:
    hostname = d['hostname'] 
    if hostname not in server_list:
        new_user_list.append(d)
        server_list.append(hostname)
        print d
```

It prints out the following output, and gives you `new_user_list`:

```
{'username': 'john', 'hostname': 'server1'}
{'username': 'jonny', 'hostname': 'server2'}
{'username': 'jules', 'hostname': 'server3'}
```

Tested using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

Sort them by username preference, and then go through the list only adding to the new list if there is no matching servername.